# Wrap email text in a way that's compatible with format=flowed e.g. using par

Tags: vim, mutt, text-formatting

I would like to wrap email text to 72 characters using a command-line program (so that reformatting can be integrated with `vim`). Quotes using `>` need to be handled nicely.

Lines longer than 72 characters should be wrapped, as well as those shorter than 72 characters and ending with a space. Lines not ending with a space should be left alone so that you can write something like

```
Best wishes,
Greg
```

(with no space after `Best wishes,`) without it being wrapped into a single line.

Where lines are wrapped, a trailing space should be left at the end so that when the email is sent using the [`format=flowed` `Content-Type` header](https://joeclark.org/ffaq.html) it's displayed correctly by an email client.

Here's some example text:

```
This is an example text file that I would like to reformat using par. I would like this paragraph wrapped to 72 characters because at the moment it's just one long line of text.

> This paragraph should also be wrapped 
> to 72 characters because each line 
> except the last ends with a space. 
> The quotes should be handled nicely.

These lines shouldn't be wrapped
because they are shorter than 72 chars
and don't have any trailing spaces.
```

`par w72q` (output below) gets close, but doesn't leave trailing spaces at the end of lines and does wrap the lines with no trailing space:

```
This is an example text file that I would like to reformat using par. I
would like this paragraph wrapped to 72 characters because at the moment
it's just one long line of text.

> This paragraph should also be wrapped to 72 characters because each
> line except the last ends with a space. The quotes should be handled
> nicely.

These lines shouldn't be wrapped because they are shorter than 72 chars
and don't have any trailing spaces.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim actually handles this well without resorting to another program. The following options are useful:

```
setlocal comments=n:>
setlocal formatoptions+=aw
setlocal textwidth=72
```

See `:help format-comments` and `:help fo-table` for more info.